# MATLAB with older version to use a package

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, prompt

I want to use the pytep package for simulation. Requirements to install are environment with python 3.7 version and compatible MATLAB. Currently I created a anaconda environment with python 3.7 .

Anaconda base with the version 3.9

I installed MATLAB versions 2019b, 2020b,2023b. But the prompt showing they are not compatible with python 3.7. Tried to solve it by installing older version of MATLAB engines.

But the error is 2019b or 2020b are not the correct version. I am attaching the website how to setup the package here. If anybody can guide me I would be happy.

https://pytep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme_link.html

I would expect the steps to set it up.

Comment: Update with pith Python 3.12.1 will solve your problem.

Comment: The MATLAB documentation for Python compatibility can be found here: https://mathworks.com/support/requirements/python-compatibility.html All versions from 2019a to 2022a should be compatible with Python 3.7, please [edit] your question to include the full verbatim error message you are seeing, preferably with a [mcve] so we might reproduce the issue